# android app crashed onclick

Tags: android, eclipse

my app crashes when i run it and try to navigate to a different class using onclick comand, its just a simple intent so im clueless as to whats wrong.

this is my main code

```
package com.example.converter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

  //called when the user clicks the Temperature button */
    public void send(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Temp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

this is where in trying to go

```
package com.example.converter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Temp extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_temp, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

manifest

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.converter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Temp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_temp" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the logcat

```
> 12-05 10:14:11.544: E/AndroidRuntime(15769): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Temperature
12-05 10:14:11.544: E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
12-05 10:14:11.544: E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:962)
12-05 10:14:11.544: E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2145)
12-05 10:14:11.544: E/AndroidRuntime(15769):    ... 11 more
12-05 10:21:56.234: D/AndroidRuntime(15860): Shutting down VM
12-05 10:21:56.234: W/dalvikvm(15860): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method Temperature(View) in the activity class com.example.converter.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2152)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Temperature
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:962)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2145)
12-05 10:21:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(15860):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: share `activity_main.xml` file. I guess you write `Temperature` in `onClick` of your button.

Comment: Can you show us the xml for the MainActivity? Also, the class' name is Temp but the error says Temperature(View) doesn't exist so that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You have set `android:onclick="Temperature"` on the button you click in your layout xml, but the method name is "`send`". Change the method name to "`send`" in your layout xml:

```
android:onclick="send"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your XML of UI if you are setting `android:onclick="Temperature"` then change it to `android:onclick="send"`

Answer (score 0):

In this portion of your code,

```
//called when the user clicks the Temperature button */
public void send(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Temp.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You must have have the following attribute defined to your `Button` (I am assuming) in your `activity_main.xml`:

```
android:onClick="send"
```

Alternatively, you can assign the `Button` an id like this:

```
android:id="@+id/btnShow"
```

And in your `MainActivity`:

```
Button btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow)
btnShow .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Temp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: does it make a difference which way i do it, or is it just a preferance, cause is it a better way to code that to, in the future, make me a better coder and make more complex coding?

Comment: @Guparasti: Either way. It is a personal preference really. I just provided an alternative. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the main code for you:

```
package com.example.converter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//called when the user clicks the Temperature button */
public void send(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Temp.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```